# PHP: Error thrown when including and requiring files

Tags: php, include, directory, require

I tried to create a bootstrap file, but whenever I try to include or require it in another file an error like this keeps showing up:

**Warning:** require_once(../folder/file.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in...

**Fatal error:** require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '../folder/file.php' (include_path='.:') in...

To paint the entire scenario:
I have a bootstrap file, load.php. In it, I connect to the config file at ../config/config.php. Above the load file I have a database class file at classes/database.php. In the database file I wrote this if-statement:

```
           if ( file_exists('../load.php') ) {
               echo 'load.php: It exists';
               require_once('../load.php');
           } else {
                  echo 'load.php: It does not exist';
                  }
```

In the load file I wrote a similar if-statement, but checking if the config file exists. Surprisingly, when I load the database.php file I get:

```
load.php: It exists
config.php: file doesn't exist
```

But when I load the load.php file and I get:

```
config.php: It exists
```

Here is where my files are located:

**Root Directory:** /Library/WebServer/Documents/project

**config.php file** /Library/WebServer/Documents/project/config/config.php

**load.php file:** /Library/WebServer/Documents/project/includes/load.php

**database.php file:** /Library/WebServer/Documents/project/includes/classes/database.php

I need help with this bug.
Thanks,

Comment: I'm having a hard time following. Can you post your full-code and take a screenshot or ascii-art of your file-structure? That would make things a lot easier for everyone.

Comment: You are using a relative path to the files. Could you explain the file structure of where these are located... that would help explain this error.

Comment: Double check your paths. Also, where is this coming from `config.php: file doesn't exist`?

Comment: If you have load.php and config.php in a `bootstrap` directory. Then you should be mindful of the relative paths...

Comment: I included my file paths at the bottom of the main post.

Comment: All of my spelling was correct originally, but for some reason, i still got an error. When I used `dirname(__DIR__)` instead of going up and down directories using using `../` `../../` or `folder/file.php` , I was able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `dirname(__FILE__) . '../relative/path/from/file/in/which/opened/to/config.php'`. From PHP 5.3 there is also `__DIR__` constant

Comment: Thanks. After tinkering around with using `dirname(__DIR__)` I got it to work. 
Why does this work? What is wrong with simply going up and down a directory using these commands: `../` `../../` or `folder/file.php`

Comment: Because when you include some file to another one (e.g. there are three: index.php, config/config.php and app/bootstrap.php) symbol dot refers to another directory. For example
**index.php:**
`require 'app/bootsrap.php';`

**app/bootstrap.php**
`/* wrong reference to file because '..' refers to dirname of index.php file */ require '../config/config.php';` 

**config/config.php**
`/* just do nothing */`

You can use `getcwd()` to proof this behavior.

Comment: thanks. Instead of using `dirname(__FILE__)` or `dirname(__DIR__)` could I use `getcwd()`. For instance:

  `require_once(getcwd . "/" . "file.php")`