# PHP require_once error when including file in parent folder

Tags: php, require-once

I have the following file structure

--  Plugins
--  inParent.php
---- Uploadify
------ inSame.php
------ Uploadify.php

This function was working smoothly till yesterday. But now, If I try to include the **inParent.php** in **uploadify.php** using **require_once('../inparent.php)**, It giving me a silly error..saying...

```
Warning: require_once(../inParent.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/public_html/plugins/uploadify/uploadify.php on line 3
```

But the file definitely exists...

The same code when used to include **inSame.php** shows no error and works perfectly..

I guessed that there could be file permission problem.. But everything is fine..all the related files have 755/644 permissions.

Also, the move_uploaded_file function has also stopped working.

All the code was working fine till yesterday. I hav'nt changed anything.

I have tried everything and dont know what exactly happened..

Please help me friends.. :( :(

Comment: duplicate, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303033/php-error-thrown-when-including-and-requiring-files/11303128#11303128

Comment: @Serjio Thanks, but the code was working smoothly since eternity. What has caused this problem to occur? I know we can definitely include the files this way.. Then why the error ??

Comment: @Spudley nope...I know case sensitivity is annoying but this time it is not causing the error.. I have said that the same code was working fine.. I did not change anything.... But suddenly this error started showing from yesterday....

Comment: Are you opening the uploadify.php directly? or you are using another script to include it or something?

Comment: hey... why negative votes?? I am already frustrated by the problem.. now what is all negative voting stuff...

Comment: @MiroMarkarian I am calling the script from jquery..

Comment: PHP scripts don't care how they were called from the browser. Have you checked with the server administrator to see if there were any changes to php.ini?

Comment: @SharadSaxena show your jQuery code pls. And try to call `getcwd()` inside **uploadify.php**. PHP includes files based on value of this function.

Answer (score 46):

I've googled and found this :
`require_once __DIR__.'/../inParent.php';`

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to write:

`require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' . '../../inParent.php';`

And that worked!

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but for people like me who run across it, here is an answer from another part of Stack Overflow.

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/inParent.php');

[PHP require file from top directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630002/php-require-file-from-top-directory)

Answer (score 0):

If it was working yesterday and you are certain you did not change anything, then try a server restart first.

Second, on require once  try using the full path instead of ..  I normally create a file with my root paths and referance those instead of using ./ and ../

Comment: actually, I have created a file named initialize.php containing the references.. But still I need to include that initialize.php using ../

Also, **move_uploaded_file** has also stopped working giving error that the folder does not exist...( it was also working fine before) Does this **move_uploaded_file** problem is also related to it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it is really weird:

1. This Works perfect:

   `require('../../the_folder/the_file.php');`
2. But PHP gives an error if i write that as this:

   `require('../the_file.php');`

Please see that in case 2 i do not go up two steps (../../) and then down to the folder, i directly go up one step (../).

Why is PHP giving the error `Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ...`  ? It is really weird.

This also works:

```
require(__DIR__.'/../the_file.php');
```

Thanks for the TIP.